# When creating custom plots, is it better to have functions return axes objects or figures or something else?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In one .py file (module?), I have some functions to analyze data. For example, `getAllRanks(name, gender, files)` ranks a given name by its popularity year by year, where each year's data is in a separate CSV file.

In a second .py file, I am writing some functions that take the data returned by the "analysis" functions and plot it.

The plotting is working out well, but I was thinking of stepping it up.  I was thinking of having my functions return an appropriate matplotlib object, which I could collect into a list or array. After all is said and done, I could get the length of that list to determine the dimensions of my figure, the rows and columns for the subplots, etc. Then, I could iterate over my list of objects and add them to a plot that is designed to fit them. I know how to do this all in one go by using subplots, but I'm looking to create something a little more flexible here. Some psuedocode would look like:

```
def getAllRanks(name, files):
    for f in files:
        getRank(file, name)
        data[i] = year, rank

def getAllScores(name, files):
    for f in files:
        getScore(file, name) 
        data[i] = year, score

def plotPopularity(name):
    files = filedialog
    rank_data = getAllRanks(name, files)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(rank_data)

    return "SOME KIND OF OBJECT"

def plotScores(name):
    files = filedialog
    score_data = getAllScores(name)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(score_data)

    return "SOME KIND OF OBJECT"

list.append(plotScores("Sam")
list.append(plotRanks("Sam")
dims = (len(list), 1)  
# format figure dimensions and subplots based on dims here
for i in list:
    plot.add(i)
```

So my question is, what is the appropriate matplotlib object to return that I can collect and add to a customized plot later? Would that object be the instance of `ax`? Or would it be a figure? I don't think figure, since I think it's the container that will hold all of the different plots in a single window. Is it something else entirely?

**EDIT:** This might not be a prudent thing to do at all, and I am totally open to that as an answer. I'm just trying to learn matplotlib and how to visualize different data sets on my own. The documentation is really good, but I get confused because there are at least 3 ways to do everything with matplotlib, and the tutorials don't stick to a convention or explain their choices methods, so it's hard to learn from them.

Comment: In the introductory tutorial, there is a section [coding styles](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#coding-styles) which mentions how to go about this: create a function which takes an axes as input and let the function plot to that axes. potentially let it return the created object (one or more lines, an image, ...).

Comment: This tutorial is really good, but not quite the same as what I'm looking for. For example, on one plot, perhaps I want an axhline at the y value where the average occurs. perhaps on the other plot, I want to annotate a local maximum. I'd like to get these plots set up in their own functions, and then return something that allows me to add them to an overall figure. The generic "myPlotter" doesn't allow individual control like that. I'm looking to individualize my plots and then drop them in a figure, if that makes sense.

Comment: Well, yes that makes sense. But that's why you put in the axes. I don't see why such function would not allow for that.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, is that the answer to my question then? If I use `ax = plt.subplot()` and then do a bunch of tweaks like `ax.set_ylabel` and `ax.axhline(y.mean())`, can I return that `ax` instance to somehow be added to a figure later down the line? My experience is using `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and then tweaking each axis individually after a fixed number of them are already created. I want to add an arbitrary  number of them to a plot. Maybe I have 3, maybe I have 13, all in a list or array of some sort. I can use the length of that array to determine the figsize for example.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I'm sorry that I am either communicating poorly or unable to understand what you mean. I hope the last comment makes more sense.

Comment: An axes is *always* created within a figure. You cannot take it from one figure and put it into another one. (Well, technically you can, but that only works under certain conditions, is utterly cumbersome and is definitely not how one should use matplotlib.)